# Can reinforcement learning models learn to rank?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have a very simple  observation: a list of random value

```
state = [random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2) for _ in range(200)]

reward =  state * actions
```

The reward is not using the next state, it's using the previous state i gave to the model.

So basically i already give the answer to the model, the best action is :  if state > 0 action =1, if state < 0 action = -1

I tried using PPO, but it seem not learning at all.

My test_env.py is here:

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from gymnasium import spaces
from gymnasium.utils import seeding
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
import random

class TestEnv(gym.Env): 

    metadata = {"render.modes": ["human"]}

    def __init__(
        self,
        item_count,
        test_steps,
        is_train = True,
    ):
        self.is_train = is_train
        self.test_steps = test_steps
        self.steps = 0
        self.item_count = item_count
        # action_space normalization and shape is self.item_count
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, dtype=np.float32, shape=(self.item_count,))
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
            low=-np.inf,
            high=np.inf,
            shape=(1, self.item_count),
        )
        self.state = [random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2) for _ in range(self.item_count)]
        self.terminal = False
    

    def step(self, actions):
        self.steps += 1
        self.terminal = self.steps > self.test_steps     
        if self.terminal:
            return self.state, self.reward, self.terminal, False, {}
        else:
            self.reward = np.sum(self.state * actions)
            self.state = [random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2) for _ in range(self.item_count)]
            return self.state, self.reward, self.terminal, False, {"Rest" : self.test_steps - self.steps}

    def reset(
        self,
        *,
        seed=None,
        options=None,
    ):
        self.steps = 0
        self.state = [random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2) for _ in range(self.item_count)]
        self.terminal = False
        return self.state, {}

    def render(self, mode="human"):
        return self.state

    def _seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
        return [seed]

    def get_sb_env(self):
        dummy = DummyVecEnv([lambda:self]) 
        #print(f'is train {self.is_train}')
        #e = VecNormalize(dummy, training=self.is_train, norm_obs=False, norm_reward=False, clip_obs= np.infty, clip_reward = np.infty)
        #obs = e.reset()
        obs = dummy.reset()
        return dummy, obs
```

the PPO model parameter is :

```
{
            "n_steps": 4096,
            "ent_coef": 0.005,
            "learning_rate": 0.001,
            "batch_size": 256,
}
```

[PPO model learning result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czZ3F.png)

Try to find problems in my code or model config, and generate meaningful training results.